# Where are the Calendar, Task and Notes views in latest update of Evolution from Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, evolution

I have just updated my system and it looks like Evolution Calendar, Tasks and Notes views are no longer available.

Any idea about what has happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are launching `evolution --express` this starts only the email component.
Try starting `evolution` by modifying your launcher or entering this in alt+f2.

Comment: Hi, thank! It was evolution --express. I was launching Evolution at startup ... but then it crashed and I started it from Unity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have the latest version from the *official* repositories. I have the latest version installed and these features are still there.

Look at the bottom left hand corner:

[image: evolution controls]

You can click these buttons to switch view.

As revealed by [david](https://askubuntu.com/users/5338/david), these may not be visible if evolution is launched with `evolution --express`. Check this by right clicking on the Applications menu and clicking 'Edit Menus'.

The evolution launcher should look like this:

[image: edit evolution launcher]

Comment: Does it mean that in Ubuntu 10.10 , „Evolution Mail” shortcut is in fact „Evolution Express” ? Opening Alacarte, I have 2 Evolution Mail items.

Comment: Evolution was `evolution --component-mail` by default for me. Are you running the netbook edition? There might be different defaults for the desktop and netbook editions.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? I welcome feedback but it is nice to know how to improve.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Desktop edition, but it looks like after installing Unity I also got some netbook edition bits beside the unitu UI.